# Oracle [Procedure] - Sum function ignores WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I have a problem with a ORACLE Procedure, it seems that SELECT SUM  ignores my WHERE clause, and Sums up ALL of the columns instead of only those that i want to (deptno). 
However if i use one of this functions like this for example :

`select SUM(SAL) AS SALSUM FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE SCOTT.EMP.DEPTNO = 10;`

It displays the proper SUM.
What may be the problem? Thanks for help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1(numerdept IN number, money OUT number) IS
    SALSUM NUMBER;
    COMMSUM NUMBER;
WYJATEK EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    IF numerdept IN (10, 20, 30) THEN
    BEGIN
        select SUM(SAL) INTO SALSUM FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE SCOTT.EMP.DEPTNO = numerdept;
        select SUM(COMM) INTO COMMSUM FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE SCOTT.EMP.DEPTNO = numerdept;
        money := SALSUM + COMMSUM;
    END;
    ELSE RAISE WYJATEK;
    END IF;

    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN WYJATEK THEN
    BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('Wrong deptno');
    money := NULL; 
    END;
END;
-- checking -- 
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    pension number;
BEGIN
    PROCEDURE1(10, pension);
    dbms_output.put_line(pension);
END;
```

[EDIT 3] SOLUTION

```
select NVL(SUM(SAL), 0) INTO SALSUM FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE SCOTT.EMP.DEPTNO = numerdept;
select NVL(SUM(COMM), 0) INTO COMMSUM FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE SCOTT.EMP.DEPTNO = numerdept;
```

AND

```
 BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('Wrong deptno');
    money := 10; 
END;
```

Comment: WHERE filters rows, not columns. One row is one data record. A column displays one field of the records.

Comment: Please stop editing your question with another once you have a solution to the first problem. It pollutes the thread and makes it hard for other people to understand the posted answers. If you have a further question you should **ask a new question**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your input parameter has the same name as your column, so when the query sees

```
WHERE SCOTT.EMP.DEPTNO = deptno
```

it interprets `deptno` as `SCOTT.EMP.DEPTNO`, meaning that it is true for all values of `deptno`. Change the name of your input parameter and the query will work as expected.

You should also use `NVL` to ensure that the individual `SUM` values are not `NULL`, as if either of them is `NULL` that will make the sum of them `NULL` as well i.e.

```
select NVL(SUM(SAL), 0) INTO SALSUM FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE SCOTT.EMP.DEPTNO = numerdept;
select NVL(SUM(COMM), 0) INTO COMMSUM FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE SCOTT.EMP.DEPTNO = numerdept;
```

Comment: Thank you, I've changed it but now i've got another problem because there is no output. I used SERVEROUTPUT ON; before checking the function but still dont work. Any ideas ? If i try to print something other than Procedures returned number 'money' it prints, so I guess there is still something wrong with my function

Comment: You need `BEGIN ... END` around `dbms_output.put_line('Wrong deptno');
    money := NULL; ` as otherwise you are always setting `money` to `NULL` even if the procedure succeeds

Comment: @Nick: I think you are wrong. The exception block belongs to the procedure's begin and end.

Comment: @Mr Robot: You problem may be nulls. Try `NVL(SUM(SAL), 0)` and `NVL(SUM(COMM), 0)`.

Comment: @Mr Robot: As to variable names, decide for some naming convention that you always follow. I am talking about prefixes, e.g. `in_depto` or `vi_deptno` and `out_money` or `vo_money`.

Comment: It works with NVL thank you, so the problem was that i had ( NULLS) in my columns and thats why it didnt return a proper value? thats weird cause with ````select SUM(SAL) AS SALSUM FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE SCOTT.EMP.DEPTNO = 10;```` It worked perfectly fine

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes, you're right. That isn't the issue

Comment: @Mr Robot: You probably have a department without COMMs, so the COMM sum is null which you add to the SAL sum, getting a null as the result.

Comment: @MrRobot but if either value (`SALSUM` or `COMMSUM`) is `NULL`, then the sum will be `NULL`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks for figuring it out - I've added your comments into the answer to make it complete.

Comment: Thanks guys for help, much appreciated